# Rest WCF that accesses a SQL Server database

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a RESTful WCF service that accesses a SQL Server database. Using it I can access the database when it runs on IIS Express, but when it runs on local IIS, it returns nothing from the database!

Here is the the method in the contracts:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getdata",
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<DbData> getData();
```

and here is the `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="AlamalConStr" 
           connectionString="Data Source=.;  Initial Catalog=trial_web_service_db;Integrated Security=True" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
       <service name="AlamalBankWCFService.AlamalService">
           <endpoint kind="webHttpEndpoint" contract="ServiceLib.IAlamalService">
              <identity>
                 <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>
           </endpoint>
       </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I run this WCF service on IIS Express, it returns the data from the database, but when I host it on Local IIS and run it it does not return data from database it shows empty page with [] only!

Comment: Please share the part of your code that you think is causing you trouble. Please specify what went wrong.

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to check the userid of your app pool. Check with that app pool user id has access to connect to SQL server. Either add the app pool id to sql server or change connection string to use SQL authentication. i.e. Use user id and password in connection string for a user created in sql server.

Some more help here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx

Comment: where to get the userid of my app pool @theusguy?

Comment: thanx, adding user id and password in connection string for a user created in sql server worked, u saved my time